# How do I hide a button after a current user clicks on a button in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to hide this button in ruby once it is clicked so it doesn't show up again and the user thinks their request has not went through. I just want this clickable once then removed from page not just disabled

```
<% if @ride_request clicks %>
  <%= link_to "Book Ride",  :controller => "/request", :action => "book", :id => @ride.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `disable_with`, which IIRC works with both `link_to` and submit buttons:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 1):

You can this javascript (jQuery) inside your controller specific .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#replace_id').click(function (){
        $(this).hide();
        });
});
```

All you need to do now is add the id of the object and substitute it with `replace_id`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try jQuery's `element.hide()` http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide

or you could toggle css' `display:none` for that button

or you could try jQuery's `element.remove()` http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_remove.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually about JS, rather than Rails.

You have to remember Rails is a server-side framework, which means it takes a request from the front-end, and then processes a response for you. This means that any UX stuff on the front-end needs to be handled with JS

To do that, you'd be best using the [`$("element").remove();`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function of Javascript:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbvA2/)

```
$(document).on("click", "element", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(150, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This will fade the button out, and then remove it from the DOM